# Multisite subdomain microsite on secondary domain

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I have a WP multisite installation that I use to host several websites for a few nonprofits that I’m a part of. I’m trying to launch a microsite for one of the domains, but can’t seem to make it work.

The installation is running as a subdomain installation, with `domain1.com` as the main domain. Then I have a website running for `www.domain2.org` and I’d like to launch a new Site in my WP installation that resolves to `event.domain2.org`.

Are there any tricks to making this work?

Answer (score 0):

After you create the sub-site, go into the Site Settings (via the Network Admin) and change the URL for the sub-site to https://event2.domain.com .

That's the same way that you would assign another domain name to a sub-site. For example, if the main site is [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com), sub-site 1 would be [www.domain.com/subsiteone](http://www.domain.com/subsiteone)  (you decided the subfolder name). That is what you use when you create it.

Then change [www.example.com/subsiteone](http://www.example.com/subsiteone) to event2.domain.com . Since your hosting nameservers know about 'domain.com', that shouldn't require any additional configuration changes at the hosting level.

Answer (score 0):

Kyle here, and I can't figure out how to respond in another way.

I tried what you said, but I think the issue is that the subdomain that I want to use is tied to a secondary domain, not the main domain of my website. Does that make sense?